# Rotate only ONE image onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display a gallery with multiple images, and i would like that each image would have a button to rotate each image.

So, following the idea of the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57540411/html-js-rotate-image-90-degrees-on-click), I created below code:

```js
const Root = document.documentElement,
  gRoot = getComputedStyle(Root)

var RotateDeg = parseInt(gRoot.getPropertyValue('--turn'))

function rotate90() {
  RotateDeg = (RotateDeg + 90) % 360
  Root.style.setProperty('--turn', RotateDeg + "deg")
}
```

```css
img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

:root {
  --turn: 0deg;
}

#theImage {
  -webkit-transform: rotate( var(--turn));
  -moz-transform: rotate( var(--turn));
  -ms-transform: rotate( var(--turn));
  -o-transform: rotate( var(--turn));
  transform: rotate( var(--turn));
}
```

```html
<div class="card shadow-sm">
  <img id="theImage" alt="text of my image 1" class="img-thumbnail card-img-top" property="contentUrl" src="myimage1.png" /><br/>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" onclick="rotate90()">Rotar</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="card shadow-sm">
  <img id="theImage" alt="text of my image 2" class="img-thumbnail card-img-top" property="contentUrl" src="myimage2.png" /><br/>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary" onclick="rotate90()">Rotar</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

So, it works partialy,  the main problem I have is that when i click one button, it not only rotates its image but ALL images. I think the main reason is because it is using the same ID. The problem i have is that it is a gallery with thousand of images and i wouldn't like to create an ID for each image.

Is there any solution i could use here to rotate just 1 image without creating thousand of IDs?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The word **image**, found in the answer, refers to an image that is part of the gallery of images that have the rotation effect.
>
> The word **button** refers to the button that triggers the rotation effect on an image.

---

Let me start by showcasing the main issue here that led to all the images being rotated regardless of the button that was clicked.

- Your `rotate90()` function adds increment the `--turn custom property` (also called `CSS variable`) by `90deg` each time a button is clicked
- The `--turn` variable is declared under the `:root` element which means that it is inherited by all elements on the page, including the images.
- when the `rotate90()` function is executed the `--turn` is incremented and its value is also updated on **all** the images which leads to **all** the images rotate regardless of the button that was clicked.

With that being explained, a quick fix could be as follows:

> The solution that am going to describe is **NOT** the only possible way to achieve your goal, there are many ways to do so but it all depends on the case.

1. In the `CSS` part, move the `--turn` declaration to the `img` selector so that each image on the page will have its own copy of that variable.
2. Give each image an `ID` (the `ID`s must be unique).
3. Tell each button which image to rotate when clicked, i.e connect each button to its image. We may do that by using [`Data Attributes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) by adding, for example, `data-rotate` to each button where that data attribute contains the `ID` of the image that the button should rotate.
4. In the `JS` part, apply `click` listeners to those buttons and change the rotation of the corresponding image.

Here's a live demo that demonstrates the above solution:

```js
/** loop through the buttons */
document.querySelectorAll('.rotation-trigger').forEach(btn => {
  /** 
   * select and cache the related image (for better performance)  
   * as each button has a "data-rotate" that is the ID of the respective button 
   * we use the value in "data-rotate" to select the respective image by calling "document.getElementById" and passing the ID which found in the "data-rotate" (btn.dataset.rotate)
   */
  const imgToRotate = document.getElementById(btn.dataset.rotate);
  /** listen for click event on each button */
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    /** update the "--turn" custom attribute, this will affect only the related image and NOT all the images */
    imgToRotate.style.setProperty('--turn', (+imgToRotate.style.getPropertyValue('--turn').replace('deg', '') + 90 % 360) + 'deg');
  });
});
```

```css
/** each image will have its own copy of "--turn" variable that can be updated without affecting the other buttons */

img {
  --turn: 0deg;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  transform: rotate(var(--turn));
  transition: all .4s 0s ease;
  /** not required, this adds an appealing transition when --turn is updated */
}
```

```html
<!-- each image has a unique ID -->
<!-- each button has a data-rotate that points to the respective image ID -->
<!-- removed click listener from the HTML, check the JS part -->
<!-- I have also gave "rotation-trigger" class to the buttons to easily select them in the JS part -->
<div class="card shadow-sm">
  <img id="img-1" alt="text of my image 1" class="img-thumbnail card-img-top" property="contentUrl" src="//via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image+%231" /><br/>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary rotation-trigger" data-rotate="img-1">Rotar</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="card shadow-sm">
  <img id="img-2" alt="text of my image 2" class="img-thumbnail card-img-top" property="contentUrl" src="//via.placeholder.com/150?text=Image+%232" /><br/>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary rotation-trigger" data-rotate="img-2">Rotar</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

> As I mentioned above, the solution found in the answer is not the only possible solution, matter of fact, I tried to keep the above solution as simple as possible so that it can be understood quite easily.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I see it works perfectly in the snippet, but somehow when i just write it on my html encapsulating the script and style it does not work. Any idea? Thanks anyway.